# iOS Send data via Internet when connection is enable

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

I'm working on an app that should work without connection. The user can insert some data and when the app detects that Internet connection is enable, it have to send this data.

Internet connection can be WIFI or carrier connection.

How I can do that? I found something called "Reachability", but I'm not sure.

The app must support iOS6 and iOS7

Comment: do you know how to prepare your data and send your data when there is an internet connection available?

Comment: Yes, for example, the user write into a uitextfield and I save the text using CoreData,

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

You want to know how your application can notify you of a network change in the user's iOS device so that you can send the data to your server once there is an active internet connection available.

**Solution:**

As mentioned in your post, you have already found the `Reachability` class, simply import it, and find your `AppDelegate.m` file and in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method add the following code

```
// This sets up a notification system for internet connections
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) 
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

// Set up Reachability
internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[internetReachable startNotifier];
```

Notice the selector `checkNetworkStatus:` that we want to have called when there is a notification change, so thats what we will do now:

```
// This method is called called whenever there is a change in network status
- (void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice {

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(internetStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down. So don't do anything");
        break;
    }
    else if((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN))
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI OR via a cellular network, Thus");
        NSLog(@"Call your method in this code block to send the data to your server");
        [self sendApplicationPreparedData];
        break;            
    }
}
```

The checkNetworkStatus only gets called by the notification sent from Reachability whenever there is a network change, and when there is an active internet connection your custom method named `sendApplicationPreparedData` will get called.

```
-(void)sendApplicationPreparedData{
    //Your code that is responsible for sending your application data to your server
}
```

Comment: if we use reachability in our app will it give notifications every time there is internet connectivity even the app is not running..

Comment: BalaChandra, a better aproximation can be remove the observer when I send the data and I haven't got more data? And when the user inserts data (without connection), I store it and I add the observer again ??

Comment: @BalaChandra No and yes, while you cant check for an internet connection continually in the background, you can however  do interesting stuff such as downloading data using apple's new Background Fetch API in iOS 7.

Comment: @Pavan I have checked that background fetch API but i dint understand one thing.. what i have to do in my application is to send some data when the user presses save.. that data will be saved temporarily and i have to send it to the server when there is network services available..

Comment: @BalaChandra lol Chandra, I understood your question. :) Please do read my answer carefully, I have written your program for you! the code sample is there, aha :D Study my code, learn it brother, and then implement it!

Comment: @BalaChandra lol Chandra, I understood your question. :) Please do read my answer carefully, I have written your program for you! the code sample is there, aha :D Study my code, learn it brother, and then implement it! All you have to do is create an IBAction linked to your button and then test the `internetReachability` variable we created in the `.h` file, it will have the the status of the internet connection. then you do a simple if else statement where if there is a connection upon button press you simply send the data there and then

Comment: @BalaChandra continued. And if there is no internet connection from the time the user pressed the button, you perhaps can store a boolean value called `ShouldSendDataWhenInternetAvailable` lol sorry for the long variable name ;) and then whenever the notification method gets called, if that boolean value is set to true then you send the data from the notification method instead. and then set the boolean value to false so that you dont send multiple requests.

Comment: @Pavan I understood it. But my only doubt is will i get a notification even when the app is not running.. any how i will try your solution.. thanks for the input :)

Comment: @BalaChandra Please refer to my third comment where I answered that question already bro. It seems you cant continually check for an internet connection in the background, but I believe you can schedule tasks for your apps in ios 7, you need to do some research on registering your device for background tasks so that maybe you can call a method that quickly checks if there is internet connection available.

Comment: @Pavan We can't continually check for an internet connection.. but i think there should be an option like the mail app automatically syncs when there is network, i will do some research.. Thanks for the detailed explanation.. :)

Comment: @BalaChandra When you say internet connection in the background are you talking about when the application is closed? or when the user is using your application but the application would check for an internet connection behind the interface?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44662/discussion-between-pavan-and-balachandra)